# Nginx redirect from non existing subdomains

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, config

I have got https://example.com

Also has https://admin.example.com

and https://forum.example.com

When request to example.com or admin.example.com or forum.example.com nginx redirects to SSL connection (https://example.com etc..)

example.com.conf :

```
server {
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 128M;

listen 443 ssl;

server_name example.com www.example.com;
root        /var/www/example.com/...;
index       index.php;

ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AE$
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/example.com-access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com-error.log;

location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    access_log   off;
    expires      7d;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny all;
}

# let's encrypt (ssl folder)
location ~ /.well-known {
     allow all;
}
} 

server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com  www.example.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
```

if i request non existing subdomains like xxx.example.com it redirects to https://example.com via default.conf

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

But if i request https://xxx.example.com it opening like admin.example.com with SSL sert error. But i need to redirect it also like xxx.example.com request.

If I appending default.conf with

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://example.com;
}
```

I'm getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED to all my hosts.

Comment: Cleaned default_server from default.conf and add it to example.com.conf. Yes i have sert error when requesting 'https://xxx.example.com' but after have redirect to 'https://example.com' as i wanted. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

> But if i request https://xxx.example.com it opening like admin.example.com with SSL cert error. But I need to redirect it also like xxx.example.com request.

No way. Redirection needs a valid certificate because the redirect happens only after the certificate was checked. Without a certificate matching the URL you get only a certificate error and it will not reach the redirect.

Comment: Thanks much. I understand about certificate error, but why any not existing subdomain such as https://xxx.example.com reachs https://admin.example.com?

Comment: @ZeiZ: because they are all on the same IP address and you either listen for SSL on a IP address or you don't. And if there is no specific configuration matching the requested name it will just use the default entry for this IP address which happens to be your admin subdomain.

Comment: "default entry for this IP address which happens to be your admin subdomain". So if i don't want to have admin as default entry? what i need to do?

Comment: @ZeiZ: change the order in your config or add an explicit default entry for ssl (like you've tried) which also contains certificate and key (which you've missed).